# Как во Flask можно получить данные POST запроса в виде объекта?

Tags: flask

Как можно получить данные POST запроса в виде объекта?

Как получить в виде Dictionary я знаю:  request.get_json(). Это не то, что мне нужно.

Так как из js скрипта в POST параметре передается сложный объект, где в свойстве object также хранится объект:

"{"object":{"comment":"sdf"},"table":"UdoRec","recordId":"2"}"

то хотелось бы на сервере восстановить его в таком же виде.

Comment: Что значит восстановить в таком же виде? Преобразовать в словарь? Или наоборот получить данные в виде строки?

Comment: Ну, можно и в виде строки

Comment: А, кстати, в каком виде хранятся данные, передаваемые POST запросом в самом объекте request? (contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8") У меня нет нормального отладчика, чтобы посмотреть

Comment: Если нужно просто получить данные в виде строки, то `request.data`

Comment: И правда... Спасибо огромное,  insolor!

Answer (score 0):

Данные из `request` объекта вы можете получить обратившись к атрибуту `request.data`